# Add a role to people that react with a certain emoji in a certain channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord.js bot for my server I made for people in my school. I'm trying to make a `#classes` channel and if you react to certain messages it gives you a role (which gives you access to the text channel for that class).

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log("client.on completed.")
  if (message.channel.name === 'classes') {
    console.log("if(message) completed.")
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "reminder_ribbon") {
      console.log("emoji test completed.")
      const guildMember = reaction.message.guild.members.get(user.id);
      const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "FACS");
      guildMember.addRole(role);
    }
  }
});
```

This is what I have tried so far, however, it does not give me/the other people reacted to it the role nor does it return an error message.

P.S. Also, how would I be able to make it so when they unreact it removes the role?

Edit: It seems it only gets reactions from cached messages/messages sent after bot startup.  Also, message is not defined on the first if(message.channel.id) message.

Comment: You also use `<message>` although this is not defined in your scope, just `reaction` and `user`. When remove a reaction, the `messageReactionRemove` event is emitted and then you can use `.removeRole('id');`

Comment: How would I go about making sure the channel is the #classes channel?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.channel.id === '552708152232116224') {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "reminder_ribbon") {
      const guildMember = reaction.message.guild.members.get(user.id);
      const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.get('552709290427940875');
      guildMember.addRole(role);
    }
  }
});
```

First of all, `reaction.users` is an Object with all the users that reacted on the message, so you first have to define to which user you want to assign the role. I fixed this fetching the `guildMember` with `user.id`.

The second mistake was that you tried to assign a role ID to a `guildMember` although you first have to fetch the role and then assign the role Object to the `guildMember`.

Comment: This did the same thing as my other code; do nothing.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Maybe the if (message.... etc. is incorrect? If so, how would I go about fixing that? It is supposed to make sure that the reaction was in #classes

Comment: You can also check this using `message.channel.name === 'classes'` (Just works if you have just one guild text channel with this name)

Comment: But is there any error that is thrown in your console? I can't help you without knowing where I have to look for bugs...

Comment: There are no errors.  Perhaps it is not being triggered? Does that mean it would be a problem in the first of the 2 "if() {"s? Otherwise, it would be working or returning/logging errors.

Comment: Try to set different console logs after every line to see where we have to search for issues

Comment: It did not give me any of the console logs, meaning it must be a problem in the first line:

`client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {`

Comment: This line is correct! You can see an example of the guildMemberAdd event here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/greeting

Comment: So then what is going on? I will list my entire code in pastebin (excluding the bot token ofc).
https://pastebin.com/hmDkijva

Comment: Dou you even trigger this event by reacting on a Discord text message on a Discord server?

Comment: I'm sure I have done it at least 10 times.  I will try in an empty and new server

Comment: I have figured out the problem.  The bot only reads reactions from messages sent after it has been turned on. After this, message was not defined in the first i if() message. Any help on these would be great.

Comment: @The_Lava_Wielder Oh yes next time you have to write this in your problem description. The reason for that is because the bot only fetches messages that were sent during he was online

Comment: I've found this: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1376 but when I put it in, making Client Discord.Client (otherwise it does not work) it does nothing. Am I using it wrong?