# How to check to see if a reaction is posted in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js bot that I would like to have a gateway entry on. It works that when they react to a reaction on a message, they get a role. How would I be able to accomplish that?

Comment: What are you having issue with ? Can you add your current code in your question ? Have you tried searching for similar questions on SO ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078438/add-a-role-to-people-that-react-with-a-certain-emoji-in-a-certain-channel (Even if that question is not marked as solved it should be a pretty good starting point)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you find this useful :)

```js
flutter.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {



  let welcomeRole = member.guild.roles.find(role => {return role.id==="ROLE ID"});

  await member.addRole(welcomeRole);

  Promise.resolve(flutter.channels.get("CHANNEL ID")).then(async welcome => {

  const msg = `Welcome to the community. :emojiName: We are **please** that you have joined us!`; 

  Promise.resolve(welcome.send(msg)).then(async message => {



    flutter.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {

        if(user === message.author.bot) return;

        if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {





            let role = member.guild.roles.find(role => {return role.id==="ROLE TO REMOVE ID"});

            await member.removeRole(role);

            let roleTwo = member.guild.roles.find(role => {return role.id==="ROLE TO ADD ID"});

            await member.addRole(roleTwo); 

        }

      });

   });

  });

});
```

Wherever you see the word `flutter` just change it with your bots client name.

```js
Example:

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Best of luck~